# Exception has occurred. _TypeError (type 'Container' is not a subtype of type 'String')

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to show the user image URL In the CircleAvatar(); It's showing a null error even though I've provided it. Or am I doing it wrong?

First I call the Auth Methods and Set image **String img**,

```
  AuthMethods _auth = AuthMethods();
  String img;
```

I then instantiate in initstate

```
    _auth.getCurrentUser().then((user) async {
      setState(() {
        user.uid;

        img = user.photoUrl

      });
    });
  }
```

Then call it in the **Drawer()**

```
  DrawerHeader(
    child: CircleAvatar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
      radius: 100,
      child: Image(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        image: NetworkImage(
              img != null ? img : Container(),  // <== here
            ) ??
            CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    ),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.orange,
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

NetworkImage takes a String as perimeter, not a widget.
In your case:

```
NetworkImage(
              img != null ? img : Container(),  // <== here
            )
```

if img i.e. String is null than you are returning Container(), but you should return a String (maybe you can give an empty string)

Answer (score 0):

NetworkImage takes image URL in its String parameter, in your case you are passing either image URL or Widget into this parameter and obviously Widget is not String. Your null check should be above NetworkImage like this:

```
...

image: 
   img != null ? NetworkImage(img) 
               :
            CircularProgressIndicator(),
 //Or container or different desired widget in case image path is null
...
```